# i am interested in knowing about Full Screen Modal Window

Tags: usability, popup

[image]

Please specify about where to use full window modal over Modal popup. Refer attached images

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, I am working for design paradigm where I want to specify the usage difference between Full screen modal window and pop-up modal window.

Answer (score 0):

Principally when you dont want lost the focus about the information of your main page you use a Modal popup...
Can you tell us any more information about your issue?